# Suggestions for Creating an Image for Each Word in a Text

Tags: c++, perl, image, bash, unicode

I am looking for a way to automatically create an image rendering for each word in a text file (I am working on an "easy" way to display a complex script on computers and cell phones that don't support the complex script).  Is there an easy way to do something like this?  The text will be in Khmer (UTF-8).  I've already tried imagettftext (php) but it doesn't seem to be compatible with Khmer Unicode fonts [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774401/how-to-create-an-image-using-utf-8-text-and-php-imagettftext).
The word separation character is not a normal space as in English, but a zero-width space (U+0200B).

Sample Text:
កាល​ដើម​ដំបូង​ឡើយ ព្រះ​បាន​បង្កើត​ផ្ទៃ​មេឃ និង​ផែនដី។

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Gtk3::WebKit](http://p3rl.org/Gtk3::WebKit) to capture rendered HTML to any [libcairo](http://cairographics.org/) output target.

As of 2011, this is the most modern and flexible solution.

---

[image]
Sample rendering to PNG of the whole Khmer phrase

Comment: Thanks Daxim, that looks like the best solution out there.  I do see a problem with the rendering - one of the vowels is in the wrong position, but I will mess around with it and see if perhaps it is a font issue, because everything else looks great!

Comment: @Daxim, Would you be willing to give me some step by step instructions on how you rendered the Khmer text with Gtk3 and libcairo?  I tried to get started but haven't been able to get it to run (in Ubuntu).  I was able to get a php version of pango and cairo running, but I am having trouble getting the width of the png to be variable based on the text length.

Comment: See the code in potyl's [s5pdf](https://github.com/potyl/Webkit/blob/master/s5pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to prerender the texts with LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

For simple I would use Perl::GD.  I have used it in the past.  Take a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php).

Comment: I explored that, so far I haven't been able to get it to render Khmer correctly...that's why this question is so broad, because I wasn't sure where to look next.  See this previous question of mine regarding imagefttext http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774401/how-to-create-an-image-using-utf-8-text-and-php-imagettftext