# Is there a way to convert epub format to images?

Tags: perl, image, language-agnostic, epub

I need a tool to programmatically convert epub files to a series of images.  The output should look like screenshots taken on a canonical device (for this application, an iPad).  I haven't been able to find any tools that do something like this.

So what I'd really like (1) is a tool that does that.  But assuming that I'm correct that no such tool exists, is there (2) a library (preferably a Perl module, but I'm not that picky) that will read and render ePub?

Obviously, rolling my own I could combine tools for unzipping, reading html, reading xml, putting everything in the right order, and rendering html within certain constraints.  Though I'd rather not do that, and if that's the only option I'll have to go on to look for a tool that will do the last part of that or I'll have to create that too.

Any leads on (1), or failing that (2)?

Comment: [EPUB](http://enwp.org/EPUB) is HTML. Capturing that is a solved problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7816618#7820994

Comment: I think this question is better fit for www.perlmonks.com

Comment: @daxim thanks - that should solve the fallthrough condition, anyway.  Still hoping for a less general solution.

Answer (score 4):

Apologies if what I'm about to type is just crazy-talk on my part--in fact, I'm pretty sure it is--but perhaps something like this might work and I'm kind of interested in knowing how well it might work for you:

Use Frank (https://github.com/moredip/Frank) to control the iOS Simulator on a Mac.  Program it to open up the EPUB docs you need.

All you need then is something to automate the taking of the screen shots.  Obviously, these will look like the EPUBs are being rendered in an iPad (or an iPhone if you wish--the iOS Simulator does both, of course).

Automating the screenshots can probably be done with AppleScript, although the hard part might be getting it to talk to Frank.  Worst case, you can tell Frank to pause for 5 seconds after it loads each page and tell AppleScript to take a screen shot every five seconds.  That sucks, but if you're desperate, it will get it done.  It's also possible Frank can somehow make the screenshots happen--I haven't used it enough to know.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but this is the closest answer so far, so bounty for you

Answer (score 1):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can convert from EPub to LaTeX (and therefore to PDF) or to any number of other formats. Conceptually this should be a type (1) solution.

Comment: It looks like Pandoc writes EPub but doesn't read it.  Still, might be a step in the right direction if I want to get my hands dirty with some Haskell.

Comment: hmmm, thats too bad, I guess I misread the page there. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

depends on your definition of "look like" - do you want the user-chrome or just the epub rendering for a given screen size.

I would check out the various epub readers for your platform of choice, size the window to your preferred dimensions, and then just "print" the epub to a virtual printer that outputs to image files - on windoze I use imageprint.

You could easily make a "frame" from an iPad product shot and place your screenshots within that - only thing missing would be as I said the user chrome.