# mechanize print to pdf

Tags: perl, mechanize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I grab a thumbnail screenshot of many websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381239/how-do-i-grab-a-thumbnail-screenshot-of-many-websites)

I wrote a script using perl mechanize to login and fetch a page. How can I "print" that page to "pdf" directly from my perl script? I'd like to save a snapshot of how it looks in the browser.

I can get the html using `$mech->content();`

Comment: See my answer in [Suggestions for Creating an Image for Each Word in a Text](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7820994/46395). PDF output is supported, and it will be a *real* PDF with selectable text and stuff, not just a huge embedded bitmapped screenshot. There isn't a Mechanize-compatible frontend for this module yet, but it can't be too difficult to write one, because [the previous version has one](http://p3rl.org/Gtk2::WebKit::Mechanize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) - there are variants for PDF and images (PNG etc). It's basically a command-line tool wrapping the webkit html engine. Works quite nicely, and it's cross-platform too. Whether you can get it past your login form will depend on how the target site works.

Comment: This does not integrate with Mechanize.

Comment: @daxim What do you mean by "integrate"?  You take the HTML from Mechanize and you feed it to wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of [CPAN modules to convert HTML to PDF](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=html%20pdf&mode=all).  Feed any of them the content from Mechanize.

Answer (score -2):

The `$mech` contain plain html so you can't just print it. Check this thread: [How do I grab a thumbnail screenshot of many websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381239/how-do-i-grab-a-thumbnail-screenshot-of-many-websites/8381303#8381303)